# Consecutive GridUnload createGrid not working

Tags: jqgrid

Any ideas why multiple calls to a function that does the following

```
grid.jqGrid('GridUnload');
createGrid();
```

Will only create the grid every other time, but ...

The following will work everytime it is called:

```
grid.jqGrid('GridUnload');
setTimeout(createGrid, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't included the code of `createGrid` so I can only guess. One possible reason is that you use `grid` variable inside. If you use `GridUnload` the old `<table>` element will be deleted and another one will be created on the same place. So you should reset the value of `grid` after call of `GridUnload`:

```js
var gridId = grid[0].id; // or grid.attr('id');
grid.jqGrid('GridUnload');
grid = $('#' + $.jgrid.jqID(gridId)); // or just $('#' + gridId);
createGrid();
```

The method `$.jgrid.jqID` you have to use only if the `id` of the grid can hold some [meta-character](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/#jq-primaryContent).